# ModalPopUpExtender makes popupcontrol invisible

Tags: modalpopupextender

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:scriptmanager ID="sc1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="links"
Visible="true">LinkButtonABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" style="display:none;">
  Display text.
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
   TargetControlID="Panel1" PopupControlID="LinkButton1">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
</form>
```

This is my code. I have tried on IE8, chrome, Safari and in all three as the page loads the LinkButton just disappears. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: What was with the random block of numbers?

Comment: those were just some text in the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I remember correctly, but your TargetControlID should be your LinkButton which should activate the popup. There is some convention to do so. I read the book Asp.net Ajax in Action, where it was described. Unfortunately I don't remember why. Your PopupControlID should be the panel.

So I guess it should look like

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="links"
Visible="true">LinkButtonABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" style="display:none;">
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
   TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Take a look at the sample [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You want to set PopupControlID="LinkButton1"

You don't have anything defined within your Panel btw.  Your panel has no content.

you want to put:

```
<asp:Panel>
  Some Stuff
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: yes. I did that. but still it is not showing the LinkButton1.

Comment: just updated my answer,  you have nothing in your panel to show.

Comment: Actually crap, my bad. I was formatting his question and saw a huge block of numbers which served no purpose other than to stretch the page, so I removed it. Then I also removed what he had inside his panel.